# Javascript If then else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to call a variable in an alert with an If then else statement.

I am creating the global variable currentmonth on page load.  I tested that a value is loading into currentmonth and it is working.

I am also creating the global variables (datejanuary through datedecember) on page load.  I have also tested those values and they are working.

Basically what I'm wanting to do is get the current month and compare it to a value from an array and display a message in an alert.  For example, the message for January would be "Mini Golf – the golf may be mini, the competition will be big.  To the winner go the spoils!" for February the message would be "Hike – it’s not about the destination, it’s about the journey."

Below is the function I created for this and I can't get it to work.  What am I missing?

```
    <script>
    function dateMonth()
    {
    var currentdate = "";
    if (currentmonth == "January")
    {
    currentdate = datejanuary;
    }
    else if (currentmonth == "February")
    {
    currentdate = datefebruary;
    }
    else if (currentmonth == "March")
    {
    currentdate = datemarch;
    }
    else if (currentmonth == "April")
    {
    currentdate = dateapril;
    }
    else if (currentmonth == "May")
    {
    currentdate = datemay;
     }
     else if (currentmonth == "June")
     {
     currentdate = datejune;
     }
     else if (currentmonth == "July")
     {
     currentdate = datejuly;
     }
     else if (currentmonth == "August")
     {
      currentdate = dateaugust;
      }
      else if (currentmonth == "September")
     {
     currentdate = dateseptember;
      }
      else if (currentmonth == "October")
      {
      currentdate = dateoctober;
      }
      else if (currentmonth == "November")
      {
      currentdate = datenovember;
      }
      else
      {
      currentdate = datedecember;
      }
      {
      vex.dialog.alert(currentdate);   
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about simply:

```
var messages = [
   "Mini Golf – the golf may be mini, the competition will be big. To the winner go the ..",
   "Hike – it’s not about the destination, it’s about the journey.",
   "..."
];

alert( messages[new Date().getMonth()] );
```

(`getMonth() == 0` for Jan)

Comment: This is brilliant!  Works like a charm.  Thank you so much.  My forehead was getting bruised from me banging it against my monitor!

Answer (score 0):

or so if you **really** need to do with if and else

```
<script>
    function dateMonth()
    {
        var currentdate = "";
        var currentmonth = new Date().getMonth()
        if (currentmonth == 1)
        {
            currentdate = datejanuary; //Your text
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 2)
        {
            currentdate = datefebruary;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 3)
        {
            currentdate = datemarch;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 4)
        {
            currentdate = dateapril;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 5)
        {
            currentdate = datemay;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 6)
        {
            currentdate = datejune;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 7)
        {
            currentdate = datejuly;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 8)
        {
            currentdate = dateaugust;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 9)
        {
            currentdate = dateseptember;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 10)
        {
            currentdate = dateoctober;
        }
        else if (currentmonth == 11
        {
            currentdate = datenovember;
        }
        else
        {
            currentdate = datedecember;
        }
        vex.dialog.alert(currentdate);   
    }
</script>
```